# Is it possible to work out rotate in degrees per second based on this rotate logic?

Tags: c#, mathematics, rotation

I have this code to rotate an object towards another at a given speed.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Rotate towards the target.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lookPosition"></param>
    private void RotateTowardsTarget(Vector3 lookPosition)
    {
        // Determine which direction to rotate towards
        Vector3 targetDirection = lookPosition - transform.position;

        // The step size is equal to speed times frame time.
        float singleStep = weaponRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        // Rotate the forward vector towards the target direction by one step
        Vector3 newDirection =
            Vector3.RotateTowards(turretYRotation.transform.forward, targetDirection, singleStep, 0.0f);

        // Draw a ray pointing at our target in
        //Debug.DrawRay(turretYRotation.transform.position, newDirection, Color.red, 3);

        newDirection.y = 0;
        // Calculate a rotation a step closer to the target and applies rotation to this object
        turretYRotation.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDirection);
    }
```

And I'd like to convert this to a "Degrees per second" to give the user useful feedback on how quickly it rotates. Is there a formulae I can apply to work it out?

Comment: Do you want `weaponRotationSpeed` to be in degrees per second, or do you want to return how fast it is rotating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `weaponRotationSpeed` defines the rotation speed in radians per second, if what you're asking is to let this variable define rotation speed in degrees per second you should change

```
float singleStep = weaponRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
```

to

```
float singleStep = (weaponRotationSpeed * (180/Math.PI)) * Time.deltaTime;
```

Comment: You can also use Mathf.Rad2Deg

Comment: Not quite, what I'd like tot do is leave the rotation code as it is, but have a way to work of "Given `weaponRotationSpeed` is X, that means the turret is rotating at Y degress a second", so I can display that to the user

Comment: So a simple radians to degrees conversion, i.e. Y = X * (180 / Math.PI), or as DMGregory stated Y = Mathf.Rad2Deg(X).